firebase senderId mismatch
I have an app, which is registered with one or more firebase projects, the first of which is static, while all others are dynamically added as needed.
This seems to work fine on the app side.
Trying to test sending notifications with a small script (nodejs) or test program (.NET), sending notification via the first static project works fine, while trying to send notifications via any of the other projects returns the error "SenderId mismatch".
Are there any options to initializeApp() that aren't retrieved from the private key json file that I'm missing?
Any other hints what could go wrong here?
Can I unregister from a project when the user isn't interested anymore in notifications from a customer's server?
